# Flask wtforms AttributeError: 'HTMLString' object has no attribute 'paginate'

Tags: flask, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Somebody has helped me with some great code here to show the same form multiple times each with a submit button, it works a treat, But as I will have hundreds of forms I need to paginate the page, I have been able to paginate pages in the past but I dont no how to use that code with a form in a for loop.
here is my code:(with lots of help from Greg)

```
@bp.route('/stock', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@bp.route('/stock/stock/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def stock():
    stocks = Stock.query.all()
    forms = []
    for stock in stocks:
        form = AddStockForm()
        form.id.default = stock.id
        form.image.default = stock.image_url
        form.date.default = stock.date
        form.description.default = stock.description
        form.event.default = stock.event
        form.achat.default = stock.achat
        form.vente.default = stock.vente
        form.sold.default = stock.sold
        forms.append(form)

    for form in forms:
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            if form.modify.data:
                stock = Stock.query.filter_by(id=form.id.data).one()
                stock.date = form.date.data
                stock.description = form.description.data
                stock.event = form.event.data
                stock.achat = form.achat.data
                stock.vente = form.vente.data
                stock.sold = form.sold.data
                db.session.add(stock)
                db.session.commit()
            elif form.delete.data:
                stock = Stock.query.filter_by(id=form.id.data).one()
                db.session.delete(stock)
                db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('stock.stock'))

        form.process()  # Do this after validate_on_submit or breaks CSRF token
        page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
        forms = forms[1].id().paginate(
             page, current_app.config['ITEMS_PER_PAGE'], False)
        next_url = url_for('stock.stock', page=forms.next_num) \
            if forms.has_next else None
        prev_url = url_for('stock.stock', page=forms.prev_num) \
            if forms.has_prev else None
    return render_template('stock/stock.html',forms=forms.items, title=Stock, stocks=stocks)
```

I am trying to use the fact "forms" is a list to paginate the results, I obviously dont understand how to do this, I have looked at [flask-paginate](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/) but I didnt understand that either!
all help is greatly needed
Warm regards, Paul.

EDIT
I have tried to use flask_pagination, here is my code:

```
@bp.route('/stock/stock/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def stock():
    search = False
    q = request.args.get('q')
    if q:
        search = True
    page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=1)
    stocks = Stock.query.all()
    forms = []
  #rest of code here#
        pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=stocks.count(), search=search, record_name='forms')
        form.process()  # Do this after validate_on_submit or breaks CSRF token
   return render_template('stock/stock.html',forms=forms, title=Stock, pagination=pagination)
```

This gives a different error "TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)" I also tried with "total=forms.count()" and got the same error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate doing this as it shows a lack of patience at the begining but this answer may help others, I solved my problem in two ways the first was the query which decides the order of display (descending or ascending) this then allowed me to use flask-paginate to display the results on several pages, I realised that I was dealing with a list, and the example by one of the developers [link](https://gist.github.com/mozillazg/69fb40067ae6d80386e10e105e6803c9) showed me the way, here is my code,

```
from flask_paginate import Pagination, get_page_args


@bp.route('/stock', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@bp.route('/stock/stock/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def stock():
    stocks = Stock.query.order_by(Stock.id.desc())# this gives order of results
    forms = []
    def get_forms(offset=0, per_page=25): #this function sets up the number of
        return forms[offset: offset + per_page]  #results per page
for stock in stocks:
    form = AddStockForm()
    form.id.default = stock.id
    form.image.default = stock.image_url
    form.date.default = stock.date
    form.description.default = stock.description
    form.event.default = stock.event
    form.achat.default = stock.achat
    form.vente.default = stock.vente
    form.sold.default = stock.sold
    forms.append(form)
for form in forms:
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.modify.data:
            stock = Stock.query.filter_by(id=form.id.data).one()
            stock.date = form.date.data
            stock.description = form.description.data
            stock.event = form.event.data
            stock.achat = form.achat.data
            stock.vente = form.vente.data
            stock.sold = form.sold.data
            db.session.add(stock)
            db.session.commit()
        elif form.delete.data:
            stock = Stock.query.filter_by(id=form.id.data).one()
            db.session.delete(stock)
            db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('stock.stock'))

    #this is the code from the link that I used to paginate
    page, per_page, offset = get_page_args(page_parameter='page',
                                           per_page_parameter='per_page')
    total = len(forms) # this code counts the resulting list to be displayed
    pagination_forms = get_forms(offset=offset, per_page=per_page)
    pagination = Pagination(page=page, per_page=per_page, total=total)
    form.process()  # Do this after validate_on_submit or breaks CSRF token

return render_template('stock/stock.html', title=Stock, stocks=stocks
                       page=page, forms=pagination_forms, per_page=per_page, pagination=pagination)
#And finally this is the pagination passed to the html
```

so this for all those numptys like me who struggle with everything but still love it.